# How to move server code in other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have some problems with multithreaded server. I want to connect more than one client to this server but i have no idea how to give all parameters in new thread.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class AffableThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
    public Socket client;

    public AffableThread(Socket client) {

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        String input, output;
        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            out.println("Server:" + input);
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();
    }
}

public class Server {

    static AffableThread mSecondThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client;

        server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("wait"); 
        String abc = "13";
        Runnable r = new AffableThread(client);
        server.close();
        System.out.println("Server closed");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

Here is a log

```
Server.java:15: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
                                                                           ^
Server.java:16: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                                                    ^
Server.java:18: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                   ^
Server.java:28: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        in.close();
                ^
Server.java:29: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        client.close();
                    ^
5 errors
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking here.  You need to provide more details.  Right now we see the compilation errors because of uncaught exceptions but that doesn't seem to match the question.

Comment: You never start a thread. Creating a runnable object does not start a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have all of your `run` logic embedded in your constructor. Clearly that will not actually run in a new thread, instead you need something like this

```
class AffableThread extends Thread implements Runnable {
    private final Socket client;

    public AffableThread(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            String input, output;
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    break;
                }
                out.println("Server:" + input);
                System.out.println(input);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your main method start the thread; like this

```
Runnable r = new AffableThread(client);
r.start(); // <-- Start the thread executing.
```